# Socket Connecting and Sending Data Received but not read on ASP.net side from Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, sockets, tcp

Hi i'm having an issue with sending a tcp socket from my android device to my Asp.net application on my PC

The problem seems to be with that ASP.net code as i get 5 bytes received but not managing to read them.

```
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(serverPort);
            listener.Start();

        }catch(SocketException se)
        {
            string s = se.Message;
            Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);
        }

        byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[5000000];
        int bytesRcvd;
        int buffersize = 1024;
        for(;;)
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;

            try
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                netStream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length);
                int totalBytesEchoed = 0;

                while ( bytesRcvd > 0)
                {
                    int nextPacket = (bytesRcvd > buffersize) ? buffersize : bytesRcvd;

                    int bytes = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                    string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                }

                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                netStream.Close();

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Read()` call on the netStream fills the data into the `rcvBuffer`, but then you try to get your string from the `data` buffer...

and you read two times before you try to get the string, once before the while and once inside the while. Maybe you can use a `do{}while()` loop.